# DRF: Aggregate similar entries name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to merge entries by name and perform addition to their other fields.

In this example, I want to get the total_cost and average_pct of entries that have the same project name.

Suppose:

```
# models.py
class Project(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subproject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    physical_pct = models.FloatField()
    cost = models.FloatField()

# serializers.py
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'

# views.py
class ProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

If I have 3 entries:

```
[
    {
        "project": "Project-X",
        "subproject": "Subproject-1",
        "physical_pct": 58,
        "cost": 1000.00
    },
    {
        "project": "Project-X",
        "subproject": "Subproject-2",
        "physical_pct": 100,
        "cost": 2000.00
    },
    {
        "project": "Project-Y",
        "subproject": "Subproject-1",
        "physical_pct": 73,
        "cost": 560.00
    }
]
```

My desired output:

```
[
    {
        "project": "Project-X",
        "average_pct": 79,
        "total_cost": 3000.00
    },
    {
        "project": "Project-Y",
        "average_pct": 73,
        "total_cost": 560.00
    }
]
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Based on the premise of [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#values), it must group by similar entries based on the field argument. However when I tried, :

```
# serializers.py
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['id', 'project', 'cost']

# views.py
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum

class ProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Project.objects.values('project').\
                   annotate(total_cost=Sum('cost'))
        return queryset
```

I get an error:

```
"Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `cost` on serializer `ProjectSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'cost'."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) before your annotation to group by project.

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum

Project.objects.values('project').annotate(
    total_cost=Sum('cost'),
    average_pct=Avg('physical_pct'),
)
```

Regarding your update, the cost field isn't present in the queryset because of the grouping. None of the fields outside of `.values()` and `.annotate()` will be present. To use the total cost in your serializer you need to use [`SerializerMethodField()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_cost = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project', 'total_cost']

    def get_total_cost(self, instance):
        return instance.total_cost
```

If you want to annotate each instance with the total cost instead of grouping and you're using Django >= 2.0 then you can do the following.

```
from django.db.models import F, Q, Sum

Project.objects.annotate(total_cost=Sum('cost', filter=Q(project=F('project'))))
```

Comment: I get it now thanks. Your answer was really useful. However, dot notation did not work when returning the instance. Thanks!

Comment: I used the arrayed key notation instead.